# Struggling to await in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I currently have this function here

```
async function checkEntry(results: any) {
    let ind = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        const e = results[i];

        await checkStuff(e); // returns void
        await checkOtherStuff(e); //returns void 
        await updateStatus(e); //returns void aswell

        ind++;
        await sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Now i would imagine that this would execute checkStuff, checkOtherStuff, updateStatus in this order and then go into the next iteration of the for-loop.

Instead it piles up promises of checkStuff and after the loop is done (console logs 10,000 of 10,000) it still gives me results of the first function called for a while.

Why does this function not run in the order I intended it to run? Or rather, why does the await keyword not block the execution of the loop for the time it takes to complete the call?

Edit: Content of the checkStuff function:

```
async function checkStuff(result: any) {
    
    try {
        const req = await https.get(result.url, async (res) => {
            if(res.statusCode == 404) console.log(result.url+' returns 404');
        });
        req.on("error", (e) => {
            // console.error(e);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code of your checkStuff function? It has to return a promise to work.

Comment: Is `checkStuff(e)` etc promises?

Comment: You need to make sure, your methods returns the promise. I can see `checkStuff ` doesn't return anything.

Comment: So I would need to create a new Promise inside checkstuff and then resolve it inside the https.get callback?

Comment: @Retosi the explanation of the answer you accepted is a bit misleading. You should read more about how `await` and `async` work. I tried to explain what is misleading in the comment section to the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the await keyword, you need to use it on a promise.

Currently `checkStuff` isn't returning a promise so you might adapt your code to resolve the promise when the callback is executed.

```js
const https = require('https');

function checkStuff(result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.get(result.url, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode == 404) {
                console.log(result.url + ' returns 404');
                reject(res);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e);
            reject(e);
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

A callback and a Promise are different.

When a method takes a callback, it says, when I've finished this task, I'll call a function of your choice.

When you use promises, you create a Promise object and return it. It will stay as "Pending" until something inside that promise calls resolve or reject. You can pass a result into resolve or reject like this `resolve(data)`.

Now by assigning this promise to a variable inside an `async` function, you have unlocked the `await` keyword. `await` will prevent your code from moving to the next line until the promise is resolved, so this helps you make your code synchronous.

```js
async function main() {
    const result = await checkStuff();
    /* 
       Result is now a Promise object in the pending state. 
       The code will not continue past the previous line 
       until the result variable changes from pending to resolved.
    */
    
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, just a small observation.  "make your code synchronous",.  It makes the code look like synchronous, but technically it's still asynchronous.

Comment: `Result is now a Promise object in the pending state.  The code will not continue past the previous line  until the result variable changes from pending to resolved.`  No that is wrong. `checkStuff()` returns a `Promise` the `await` keyword _"consumes"_ that Promise, and waits until its state changes from pending to resolved or rejected. `await` then either throws an error (if rejected)  or returns the resolved value, which in this cases then will be assigned to `result`.

Comment: `Now by assigning this promise to a variable inside an async function, you have unlocked the await keyword.` No, `await` can also be used with assigning, it can be used in an expression. `console.log(await checkStuff())` or `1 + await getSomValue() + await getAnotherValue()`. The `async` keyword _"unlocks"_ the `await` keyword. `await` always consumes the value on the right (which does not even need to be a Promise)

Answer (score 1):

[`https.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) does not provide a promise interface and `await` does not magically make your code wait for an asynchronous task to finish.

It is synthetic sugar to make it easier to work with Promises and requires a Promise to work.

If a function like `https.get` does not provide a Promise interface then you need in some way to convert it into a Promise, by e.g. wrapping a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => …)` around it.

```
const req = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  https.get(result.url, async (res) => {
    if(res.statusCode == 404) console.log(result.url+' returns 404');
    resolve()
  });
  req.on("error", (e) => {
    reject(e)
  });
})
```